# Angular 5 Ionic 3 Laravel project structure

Tags: php, angular, laravel, ionic-framework

for the first time I need to make front-end with laravel backend in ionic 3. I would like to know the structure how to implement this project. Maybe there is some starters with explanations ? Or it's very simple to do this ? Looking for a nice explanation.

I was working before with aws serverless backend and firebase.

Comment: So you need to make API with laravel with endpoints for Ionic app, look for API development with laravel

Comment: There already made backend with laravel - so now I should only call its functions ?

Comment: You could read this series http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/

Comment: For me its hard to understand if it would be like Project/client(front-end) and Project/server(backend) or it would be like one app

Comment: You are trying to build a mobile app with ionic that consumes api from a laravel backend, right?

Comment: Right, backend is done now only front-end left. You are right.

Comment: Dont really know if its api or not - because now laravel project done with html/css - website.

Answer (score 0):

Start your job today, nothing different between Laravel and other services. FE always send data to defined url and get the josn response or errors.